# How is the menora lit in the synagogue?

Tags: chanuka, synagogue, lighting, menora-chanukia

The menora in the synagogue is normally situated on the south side of the synagogue ([O Ch 671:7](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x3047)).

On which side of the menora is it lit? I can think of two options:

- The person lighting faces south and the first candle is as far as
  possible from the ark

**OR**

- The person lighting faces north and the first candle is as near as
  possible to the ark?

Answer (score 4):

[Nitei Gavriel Chanuka 40:2](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46444&st=&pgnum=223) says that the one who lights in the Shul stands with his back to the South and his face to the North. On the first night he lights the candle all the way on his right. On the subsequent nights he lights the new candle and proceeds to his right.

Comment: That's odd because in the mikdash the kohein faced south when lighting. I wonder if this is just the rule in countries west of Israel so the the lighter is facing the congregation.

Comment: @DoubleAA: That would make an interesting question, as to why we light differently than in the Mikdash. I recall one time seeing something about it.

Comment: Mishna Brurah says the same thing but sif 42 has a different explanation based off the Rishonim.